# Adding a new parameter throws an error in the pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho

I have a designed a report which works well. I am trying to add another sql query in it. Previewing the sql query works without any hiccups. 
But when I try to add the parameter for the same query, I get two different errors depending on which mysql-connector I am using.

Earlier I was using the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin and the error 
was

- org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query: (a few lines down )

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Stopped by user.

Then I changed the mysql-connector to mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin. The error changed to :-

- org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query:

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTimeoutException: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request

Any suggestions would be helpful. I am using Pentaho 5.3.0.0-213 on Windows 8.1 Pro. Although the same problem exists when I run Pentaho 5.3.0.0-213 on Ubuntu 14.04 
Thanks